# How to restart a dart server which file changes?

Tags: dart, application-restart, build-system

I'm running a web server with dart, it starts by:

```
dart server.dart
```

When I modified the project files, I hope this server can be restarted automatically. Is there any way to do it? Or is there any useful tool can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not natively in Dart until [bug 3310](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3310) is implemented.  There may well be external tools that will restart the command line when a file changes (open to other answers).

Comment: Now I'm using `node-supervisor`, it's working well. The command is: `supervisor -w lib,test -i lib/src/gen -n exit -e dart,html -x ./server0 dummy-but-required-argu`

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem developing a dart server. For vscode IDE, following [this stackoverflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564351/how-to-restart-on-save-in-visual-studio-code/49142066#49142066) I installed the [Save and Run Ext extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=padjon.save-and-run-ext) and modified it for a dart command line program:

```
{
  "saveAndRunExt": {
    "commands": [
      {
        // "match": "\\.(css$|js$|html$)",
        "match": ".dart$",
        "isShellCommand": false,
        "cmd": "workbench.action.debug.restart",
        "isAsync": false
      },
      {
        "match": ".dart$",
        "isShellCommand": false,
        "cmd": "dart.rerunLastTestDebugSession"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This will restart the server in debug mode and rerun the last test debug session if any dart file is saved. Both server and test debug sessions work.
Works great for me, at least on initial use of this extension.